# Genitive Plural

Tags: gender, declension

There is this sentence:

> Allerdings müssen sie zwischen ein und zwei Prozent ihrer Sozialgelder
> für die Leistungen der Krankenkasse abgeben.

The deklination mit unbestimmtem Artikel for Genitiv Plural should be 'Geldern'. So it should be

> ... ihrer Sozialgelder***n***

isn't it?

Comment: See https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Geld.htm

Comment: @RHa In my example sentence, it's not 'der Gelder', but 'ihrer Gelder'. From what I have learnt, the declination of possessive pronoun is the same as that of indefinite article. From [this table](https://dict.leo.org/pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHyRCkrUL_9hScDG0HPGhR9At5Xq8uQ-1TIkWxu1j49g2LkPIb_zhLO8hrGGfBQLsIUBu8dUIgtoqN0u8Zfm4MtkhxgGSRQPsKUxz79IG1bIseHHQBtmxKtFIsT6a0UzdJShl-6R52-MmeDqoHZvoAN_mh&lp=ende&lang=en/), it should be Geldern. –

Comment: This table is highly dubious. There is no plural indefinite article in German, so the column for indefinite article and plural makes no sense to me. It might be interpreted as "no article plural" but *Geldern* as genitive plural just feels wrong to me as a native spreaker.

Comment: @RHa I think the plural indefinite article in that table applies to '-mein', '-kein' etc.

Answer (score 3):

> So it should be

> > ... ihrer Sozialgeldern

> isn't it?

No, it shouldn't and it isn't.

German *Komposita* (composite nouns) always retain the declination of their last part. "Sozialgeld" is built from two words: "sozial" ("social"), which is an *Adjektiv/Adverb* and "Geld" ("money", sometimes also "funds"), which is a *Nomen* (noun). So, the way "Sozialgeld" is declinated is like "Geld" is declinated. "Geld" is a bit irregular, here is a table:

> das Geld (Nominativ singular)
> des Geldes (Genitiv singular)
> dem Geld (Dativ singular)
> das Geld (Akkusativ singular)

> die Gelder (Nominativ plural)
> der Gelder (Genitiv plural)
> den Geldern (Dativ plural)
> die Gelder (Akkusativ plural)

Now we have to find out which case is used:

> (Allerdings 1) (müssen 2) (sie 3) (zwischen ein und zwei Prozent ihrer Sozialgelder 4) (für 5) (die Leistungen der Krankenkasse 6) (abgeben 2a).

> Nevertheless they have to give up between 1 and 2 percent of their social funds(?) for the services of their social security (provider).

> 1. is the so-called *Vorfeld*, it translates to "nevertheless"
> 2. and 2a) is the *Prädikat*, the *Verb* "abgeben" along with the *Modalverb* "müssen" - have to ... give up.
> 3. is the subject of the sentence, "they"
> 4. This is the interesting part. It is an *Objekt* in *Akkusativ* (they have to give up *something*) but consisting of the "core" object itself ("1 or 2 percent") and an *Objekt* of this *Objekt*, so to say. This "sub-object" is in *Genitiv*, the most common analogon to the english *possessive*: "ihrer Sozialgelder".
> 5. introduces another *Objekt*, "for"
> 6. is this other *Objekt*, also in *Akkusativ* and constructed the same way as 4: a main part in Akkusativ ("die Leistungen", the services) and a sub-part in *Genitiv* ("der Krankenkasse", "of the social security provider").

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your detailed answer. In my example sentence, it's not 'der Gelder', but 'ihrer Gelder'. From what I have learnt, the declination of possessive pronoun is the same as that of indefinite article. From [this table](https://dict.leo.org/pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHyRCkrUL_9hScDG0HPGhR9At5Xq8uQ-1TIkWxu1j49g2LkPIb_zhLO8hrGGfBQLsIUBu8dUIgtoqN0u8Zfm4MtkhxgGSRQPsKUxz79IG1bIseHHQBtmxKtFIsT6a0UzdJShl-6R52-MmeDqoHZvoAN_mh&lp=ende&lang=en/), it should be Geldern.

Comment: @Dennis: no, it should not! Regardless of "ihrer Gelder" or "der Gelder", the *Genitiv plural* of "Geld" is "Gelder" and not "Geldern". You seem to think this is *Dativ*, but it is NOT! See under 4).

Comment: No, I know it's genitive. But from that table, it's Geldern.

Comment: @Dennis: This table is just plain wrong.The declination of the pronoun/adjective may change, but the noun is always inflected the same.